# c# Windows Service connected to Office 365

Tags: c#, api, office365

We have designed a Windows Service that will Sync document libraries from Office 365 SharePoint sites and down to a local folders.

My Question, since im a bit confussed on what people are using now

What API to use when it is Service/desktop application we are going for?
We are working with Visual Studio/C#

Best Regards

Answer (score -1):

You can use the [SharePoint Online Client Object Model (CSOM)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/microsoft.sharepoint.client.aspx)

You might also need to check [the last item modified time of a list](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/microsoft.sharepoint.client.list.lastitemmodifieddate.aspx) and [get changes for the files in a list](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/microsoft.sharepoint.client.list.getchanges(v=office.15).aspx)

**Additional**: [Know more about choosing the correct api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/general-development/choose-the-right-api-set-in-sharepoint)

Old answer:
SharePoint itself allows users to sync the library with local folders out of the box.
Go to "Library" tab in particular library and Click "Sync", then you can sync the library with a local folder.

Comment: This is the functionality he is looking for but it's not helpful because he's trying to write an application which does this.

Comment: this is not appropriate answer to the question.